# Reconstructing Your Itunes configuration after a crash

Tags: windows-7, windows-xp, itunes

My XP Pro SP3 configuration caught a bad case of winrot and I reloaded the system with Win 7/64 with great success.  Part of the reconstruction effort involves my itunes app library.

I have the Documents and Settings from the old windows XP box available as well as the contents of the itunes directory.

Using this can my library be reconstructed?  If so anybody have either instructions or pointers to that?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Apple has provided a [handy guide.](http://support.apple.com/kb/ht1451)

Although [this might be an easier solution](http://support.apple.com/kb/HT1589), and shouldn't make you resync devices. Not sure if it'll work going from xp to win 7 though.

Comment: does not seem to handle my APPs library.